# Django load test fixtures with django-nose

Tags: django, unit-testing, tdd, nosetests

How do you load test fixtures using the [django-nose](http://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) test runner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#settings.test.py 
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_nose', )
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.run_tests'

#appname/tests.py
from datetime import date,datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test.client import Client
from django.test import TestCase

class BetViewsTestCase(TestCase):
    #files placed in appname/fixtures/restaurant.json, appname/fixtures/map.json
    fixtures = ['authtestdata.json', 'restaurant.json', 'map.json']
```

Comment: Is it not possible to load test cases without the boilerplate django.test.TestCase subclass?

Comment: 1) create shell script: first load fixtures: django-admin.py loaddata foo/bar/mydata.json; run test logic; end; 2)you can load fixtures from python: from django.core import management management.call_command('loaddata', 'fixture1.json', verbosity=0)

Answer (score 2):

In your setup method, just call:

```
management.call_command('loaddata', 'Category.json', verbosity=0)
```

Then in your teardown, call:

```
management.call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)
```

You can import management from here:

```
from django.core import management
```

Comment: http://pythontesting.net/framework/nose/nose-fixture-reference/ you can use these commands on package level

Answer (score 2):

Just make the test case a subclass of FastFixtureTestCase.

```
from django_nose import FastFixtureTestCase
from myapp.models import MyModel
from nose_tools import eq_

class TestFixtureLoading(FastFixtureTestCase):
    fixtures = ['mymodel_data.yaml']

    def test_fixture_loading(self):
        eq_(1, MyModel.objects.count())
```

And then:

```
python manage.py test
```